# iTunesConnect-how to remove blank icon in Build section?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I just submitted my first app update and noticed that the icon next to the build number is blank
[image: icon]

I did the same steps as my first submission and I could see that icon back then.
Is this normal?

Comment: Your comment is like saying "if the pipe is broken go and fix it". Not helpful at all. Everybody knows that, but the question is what changes need to be made to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is because I added WatchKit extension and it and the app both use AppIcon as resource for icons. This causes the confusion even though from XCode everything looks correct and the app has the correct icon.

Change the name of one of the AppIcon resource, update plist/target, resubmit and everything looks fine now. Waiting for review

Answer (score 0):

This is completely normal if your app doesn't have an app icon (or if you just have a white icon for your app icon). However, if you do have an app icon set in your plist and it's showing up in the simulator / devices, the no.